# Подключить платежную систему к магазину

Tags: интернет-магазин

Здравствуйте, первый раз собираюсь подключить платежную систему к магазину, прочитал инструкцию робокасса, единственное что клиент хочет чтоб деньги падали на счет ВТБ банка а не на вебмани, как быть тут, подскажите что нибудь?

Comment: Простите, какие проблемы программистского плана у вас?

Comment: У меня вопрос не по программировании, вопрос, допустим если я к магазину подключу "РоббоКассу", то при покупке деньги будут поступать в кошелек "Вебмани" а моему клиенту это не нравится, он хочет чтоб деньги прямо падали в его банковский счет ВТБ банке, и вот у меня возник вопрос, как это реализовать, может кто нибудь из Хешкодовцев столкнулся с такой ситуацией?

Comment: может есть другие платежные системы которое при покупке деньги отправляется прямо к банковский счет?

Comment: @bemulima, все эти вопросы вам нужно решать с вашими заказчиками и службами техподдержки полатёжных систем напрямую. Как и любые другие организационно-финансовые вопросы.

Comment: klopp, Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

3) Вывод средств из системы:
3.1) Какими способами можно вывести деньги из аккаунта в Interkassa?
Interkassa предлагает широчайший ряд возможностей перевести деньги с баланса аккаунта Interkassa на любой счет электронной платежной системы или безналичным переводом на расчетный счет.

http://interkassa.com/index.php

Может заинтересует )

Comment: СПасибо, интересует)